# Check the driver version of the eID reader and know when it is an old version

Tags: c#, wpf, driver, pkcs#11, eid

I use pkcs11 dll in my wpf project, but i want to know what driver/software version my eID reader has so if it is an old version, we can make a popup with "update your driver for the eID reader"

part of code:

```
_pkcs11 = new Pkcs11("beidpkcs11.dll", false);
LibraryInfo Lib = _pkcs11.GetInfo();
DllVersion = Lib.CryptokiVersion;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using PKCS#11 API via managed [Pkcs11Interop](http://pkcs11interop.net/) wrapper to access your eID card but IMO this API does not provide information about the version of your smartcard reader driver. Your best shot is to try to examine `HardwareVersion` and/or `FirmwareVersion` properties of `SlotInfo` class which contains information about your smarcard reader (known as slot in PKCS#11) but these fields have slightly different meaning:

```
using (Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11("beidpkcs11.dll", true))
{
    List<Slot> slots = pkcs11.GetSlotList(false);
    foreach (Slot slot in slots)
    {
        SlotInfo slotInfo = slot.GetSlotInfo();
        // Examine slotInfo.HardwareVersion
        // Examine slotInfo.FirmwareVersion
    }
}
```

You can also try to read `SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_IFD_VERSION` reader attribute with `SCardGetAttrib()` function which is part of PC/SC interface but I am not sure whether the returned value is driver version or device hardware version. Following example reads this attribute with managed [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) wrapper:

```
using System;
using PCSC;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new SCardContext();
            context.Establish(SCardScope.System);

            var readerNames = context.GetReaders();
            if (readerNames == null || readerNames.Length < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You need at least one reader in order to run this example.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            foreach (var readerName in readerNames)
            {
                var reader = new SCardReader(context);

                Console.Write("Trying to connect to reader.. " + readerName);

                var rc = reader.Connect(readerName, SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any);
                if (rc != SCardError.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" failed. No smart card present? " + SCardHelper.StringifyError(rc) + "\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" done.");

                    byte[] attribute = null;
                    rc = reader.GetAttrib(SCardAttribute.VendorInterfaceDeviceTypeVersion, out attribute);
                    if (rc != SCardError.Success)
                        Console.WriteLine("Error by trying to receive attribute. {0}\n", SCardHelper.StringifyError(rc));
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Attribute value: {0}\n", BitConverter.ToString(attribute ?? new byte[] { }));

                    reader.Disconnect(SCardReaderDisposition.Leave);
                }
            }

            context.Release();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Other than that you would need to use some OS specific low level driver APIs but I am not familiar with any of those.

Comment: I tried to do this, but i have for both version 1.0, do you know some lower level APIs to check it with?

Comment: @MatthiasRoekoe I have updated my answer with sample code which uses PCSC API.

Comment: Can you just add a dll or something?

Comment: @MatthiasRoekoe I don't understand what do you mean by "just add a dll or something"?

Comment: I want to access the methods u write above and maybe there is a dll I need to put in my references so i can access the methods?

Comment: @MatthiasRoekoe You need to add the reference to [pcsc-sharp](https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp) library. It is also available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PCSC/).

Comment: Thanks, i can read out the info you say, but it gives 00-00-00-01, i guess it is the hardware version.. i would need the software version.